# cordova google plus plugin not getting full detail except email?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I am using [Cordova plugin to login with Google Plus on Android](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus) **not receiving User data except email.**

The success callback (second argument) only provinding email object.

```
function (obj) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj)); // Only show email
},
```

It is not provideing following contents:-

```
obj.userId       
obj.displayName  
obj.imageUrl     
obj.idToken
obj.oauthToken
obj.gender      
obj.givenName    
obj.middleName   
obj.familyName   
obj.birthday    
obj.ageRangeMin  
obj.ageRangeMax
```

I have read many articles but couldn't find out how it will show full detail.

I have also tried with  **scopes** parameter.

```
{
  'scopes': 'profile, email',
  'offline': true, 
},
```